# Восстановление таблицы в базе InnoDB MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, openserver, innodb

В результате отключение электричества, на локальном сервере под OpenServer слетела таблица в базе данных, не могу понять как ее восстановить.
В логах пишется следующее.

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Table makefish/utsna_updates in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 11703, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary.
InnoDB: Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
InnoDB: for how to resolve the issue.
2018-09-27 20:01:47 5340 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-09-27 20:01:47 5340 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-09-27 20:01:47 5340 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.38 started; log sequence number 9063666055
2018-09-27 20:01:47 5340 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2018-09-27 20:01:47 5340 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2018-09-27 20:01:47 5340 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2018-09-27 20:01:47 5340 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2018-09-27 20:01:47 5340 [Note] c:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.38'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

По инструкциям на указанной в логах странице, к сожалению не могу понять как исправить проблему.

Пытался перекинуть файлы `utsna_updates.frm` и `utsna_updates.ibd` но в словаре InnoDB естественно другие размеры и параметры прописаны для данных таблиц и сервер MySQL не стартовал.
После этого MySQL посоветовал удалить `utsna_updates.ibd` в ироде как MySQL сам пропишет нормальные данные в словарь, но к сожалению этого не произошло.
Пытался прописать в конфиге `innodb_force_recovery=1` к сожалению так же не дало полного положительного результата.

P.S. Данная таблица не нужна, ее можно удалить и потом восстановить из бекапа, необходимо исправить словарь базы.

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Я удалили вот эти файлы и сервер стартовал нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]